# Angular FlexLayout custom layout

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to create a layout similar to one done by angular material schematic for dashboard but using the angular flexlayout.

**Dashboard example**
[image]

So far I got to:

```
<div fxFlex="66" fxFlexOffset="15" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="0.5%">
      <div fxFlex="100%">
            <mat-card>
                  // content
            </mat-card>
      </div>
      <div fxFlex="50%">
            <mat-card>
                  // content
            </mat-card>
      </div>
      <div fxFlex="50%">
            <mat-card>
                  // content
            </mat-card>
      </div>
</div>
```

Which results in this:
[image]

It's doing my head in trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-card-example-jign7z) link of what you are trying to do:

You just need to use **wrap** `fxLayout="row wrap"`

The additional **wrap** value tells the Flex Layout to add `flex-flow: row wrap` to your flex container.

As per [CSS Trick](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-flow/), `flex-flow: row wrap` do the following magic:

> It defines whether the flex items are forced in a single line or can be flowed into multiple lines. If set to multiple lines, it also defines the cross-axis which determines the direction new lines are stacked in.

**PS:** When using wrap with fxLayout to wrap rows or columns, you should account for the gap sizes when specifying the child item sizes (using fxFlex).

Comment: Your link shows the end result but doesn't show code. Can you provide link to the editor

Comment: I have updated the link, now it refers to actual code.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-card-example-jign7z

Answer (score 0):

You have two rows, so you need to separate them into two different `div` (and you can drop `%` from your attributes):

```html
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="15px">
  <div fxFlex="100">
    <mat-card>
      // content
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="15px">
  <div fxFlex="50">
    <mat-card>
      // content
    </mat-card>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex="50">
    <mat-card>
      // content
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. All it does it put all 3 cards in one row, and squishes last 2 cards

Comment: It definitely works, there must be something wrong elsewhere in your setup. Take a look at the stackblitz I just made: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-card-example-8qn7bs?file=src/app/app.component.html